# How to implement WritableComparable interface?

Tags: hadoop

I need to use the method `setGroupingComparatorClass` in Job and it takes an argument of type `WritableComparable`.

I am unable to implement `WritableComparable` class.

Please help me to solve this. Regards, Bidyut

Answer (score 1):

```
    setGroupingComparatorClass(Class<? extends RawComparator> cls)
```

Define the comparator that controls which keys are grouped together for a single call to Reducer.reduce(Object, Iterable, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context)

```
    job.setGroupingComparatorClass(CustomKey.GroupComparator.class);
```

In your Customkey class you can write static method.

Add below code in your custom key class.

```
public class Customkey implements WritableComparable<IndexerKey> {

    public static class GroupComparator extends WritableComparator
            implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3385728040072507941L;

        public GroupComparator() {

            super(Customkey .class, true);

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public int compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b) {

            Customkey w1 = (Customkey ) a;

            Customkey w2 = (Customkey ) b;

            return w1.compareGroup(w2);
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I will implement this & let you know. Thanks for your support.